# A more efficient way of store the vectors from a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to store the column vectors from a for loop.

See the below code:

```
for i = 1:10
a=rand(10,1)
astore = [a a a a a a a a a a a]
end
```

I know there must be a more efficient way to do this. Especially if I where to have, say i = 1:5000?

Comment: Read about repmat.

Comment: Your for loop is useless you're overwriting `astore` after each iteration. Before the for loop create an empty `astore` matrice, `astore = []` then in your for loop: `astore = [astore a];`

Comment: @HansHirse thanks, but above is my example of a complete and minimal example, I am actually running a regression and getting the parameter values each time

Comment: The method from @obchardon works perfectly, can you please make this an answer!

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in the comments, you want to append to `astore`, rather than overwrite it each loop.

You should pre-allocate your output for memory efficiency

```
k = 10; % number of iterations
aHeight = 10; % Height of each a matrix in the loop. 
astore = NaN( aHeight, k );
for ii = 1:k
    a = rand( aHeight, 1 );
    astore( :, ii ) = a;
end
```

I'm assuming `aHeight` is consistent from your example, but if it's not you can use a cell array

```
k = 10;
astore = cell( 1, k );
for ii = 1:k
    a = rand( 10, 1 ); % could be anything
    astore{ ii } = a;
end
```

Pre-allocation is better than appending within a loop using methods like `astore(end+1) = a` or `astore = [astore, a]`. Although these are both valid options.